# Populate values from table to another in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a new bee  on Oracle.
I have to create a Trigger that will allow me to copy data (from a specific fields) for a table X to the table Y `before insert` of a new record base on their Keys (`IPARKEY` for X,and `IDNUMPARTICIPANT` for Y).

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DATA_IDOCUMENTS_INSERT_TRIGER
BEFORE insert on Y 
for each row

DECLARE
CURSOR c IS
SELECT IPARNOM,IPARPRENOM,IPARDATENAISSANCE,IPARNUMSECU
from X   WHERE IPARKEY = :NEW.IDNUMPARTICIPANT;
rc c%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN c;
LOOP
FETCH c INTO rc;
-- THOSE ARE THE NEEDED fIELDS TO BE POPULATED.. 
new.IDNOM:= rc.IPARNOM;
new.IPARDATENAISSANCE := rc.IPARDATENAISSANCE
EXIT WHEN c % NOTFOUND;

END LOOP;
END;
```

it is obvious that i did  write wrongly the trigger so i will appreciate your Help to fix it and get the needed business .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already declared the cursor, your loop can be a bit more concise:

```
create or replace trigger data_idocuments_insert_triger
   before insert on y
   for each row

declare
   cursor c is
      select iparnom
            ,iparprenom
            ,ipardatenaissance
            ,iparnumsecu
        from x
       where iparkey = :new.idnumparticipant;
begin
   for r in c loop
      -- THOSE ARE THE NEEDED fIELDS TO BE POPULATED.. 
      :new.idnom             := r.iparnom;
      :new.ipardatenaissance := r.ipardatenaissance    
   end loop;
end;
```

Of course, if your query returns more than 1 row you will end up with the last value to be assigned to the columns in Y.
If you are sure there will be at most 1 record you can rewrite to:

```
create or replace trigger data_idocuments_insert_triger
   before insert on y
   for each row

begin
   select iparnom
         ,ipardatenaissance
     into :new.idnom
         ,:new.ipardatenaissance
     from x
    where iparkey = :new.idnumparticipant;
exception
   when no_data_found then
      null;
end;
```

You can be only sure the query returns at most 1 record if x.iparkey is a primary or unique key.

Comment: Thank you i guess i will go for your second trigger since it is a PK